# Age word prob|em in prolog

Tags: prolog

I know that: 
Nick = 2 * Kate 
(Kate + Lea) = 2 * Nick 
(Chris + Nick) = 2 * (Kate + Lea) 
**Ashley = 24** 
Ashley + Kate + Lea = 2 * (Chris + Nick)

After some cancellation I found out that: 
Ashley = 12 * Kate => **Kate = 2** 
Lea = 3 * Kate => **Lea = 6** 
Nick = 2 * Kate => **Nick = 4** 
Chris = 6 * Kate => **Chris = 12**

I tried this:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

ages(As) :-
   As = [Ashley, Lea, Nick, Chris, Kate],
   Ashley #= 24,
   12 * Kate #= Ashley,
   Lea #= 3*Kate,
   Nick #= 2*Kate,
   Chris #= 6*Kate.
```

Output:

```
Ashley = 24,
Chris = 12,
Kate = 2,
Lea = 6,
Nick = 4
```

Solution above worked fine, but teacher told me that I can't use cancellation. I'm a little bit confused because without cancellation it doesn't work.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

ages(As) :-
   As = [Ashley, Lea, Nick, Chris, Kate],
   Ashley #= 24,
   Lea + Kate #= 2 * Nick,
   Chris + Nick #= 2 * (Kate + Lea),
   Nick #= 2 * Kate,
   Ashley + Kate + Lea #= 2*(Nick + Chris).
```

Output:

```
Ashley = 24,
Lea+Kate+24#=2*Nick+2*Chris,
Chris+Nick#=2*Lea+2*Kate,
Lea+Kate#=2*Nick,
2*Kate#=Nick
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call `age/1` as is, you get residual goals (see [CLP(FD)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) documentation for details) as an answer:

```
?- ages(As).
As = [24, _G1642, _G1645, _G1648, _G1651],
_G1642+ -2*_G1645+ -2*_G1648+_G1651#= -24,
-2*_G1642+_G1645+_G1648+ -2*_G1651#=0,
_G1642+ -2*_G1645+_G1651#=0,
2*_G1651#=_G1645.
```

In order to get actual numbers you have to restrict the range of the numbers and label subsequently. Since no one is known to have reached 200 years, an age restriction of 0 to 200 seems reasonable. Then your query delivers actual numbers as an answer:

```
?- ages(As), As ins 0..200, label(As).
As = [24, 6, 4, 12, 2].
```

This solves your immediate problem. However, I'd like to add two further notes. Firstly, it yields more clearly readable code to separate the domain restriction and labeling part from the predicate that describes the actual relation. Secondly, it would aid the readability of the result to have pairs of name-age in the list. To illustrate these points let's define a predicate `ages2/1` that calls the core relation `ages2_/2` and subsequently restricts and labels the ages. The core relation separates the ages from the names and provides said ages in a second list, after all these are the variables that you want to label. This allows you to have arbitrarily complex terms in the single list of the calling predicate `ages2/1`. Subsequently you can post your constraints as you did in `ages/1`. Putting these ideas together might look something like this:

```
ages2(NAs) :-
   ages2_(NAs,As),
   As ins 0..200,
   label(As).

ages2_(NAs,As) :-
   NAs = [ashley-Ashley, lea-Lea, nick-Nick, chris-Chris, kate-Kate],
   As = [Ashley, Lea, Nick, Chris, Kate],
   Ashley #= 24,
   Lea + Kate #= 2 * Nick,
   Chris + Nick #= 2 * (Kate + Lea),
   Nick #= 2 * Kate,
   Ashley + Kate + Lea #= 2*(Nick + Chris).

?- ages2(As).
As = [ashley-24, lea-6, nick-4, chris-12, kate-2].
```